# Integrating SonarQube with DevOps

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines, devops, sonarscanner

I have a self-hosted Windows agent that also has SonarQube Server installed on it. When I add 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube' to a pipeline, it succeeds. When I add 'Run Code Analysis' to that same pipeline, it fails with the error: ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. My sonar-project.properties file contains my sonar.projectKey and sonar.login=. I also have tried providing the sonar.login and sonar.password but it still fails. Error image link[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MesEa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message directly mentions you need to check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.

The credentials have to be under the `sonar.` namespace. Please check it.

```
sonarRunner: {
    analysis: {
        options: {
            ...
            sonar: {
                login: 'admin',
                password: 'admin',
                host: {
                    url: 'http://localhost:9000'
                },
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In addition ,you can refer to the similar [case](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/not-authorized-please-check-the-properties-sonar-login-and-sonar-password/17452) on sonarsource community.